# Route is downloading page instead of displaying it

Tags: javascript, html, express, routes

I've got a really simple page using express and when I hit my route it downloads the page instead of displaying it. I'm going from the index page, which loads fine, to the faq page, which is the only other page so far. I'm using ejs templating, so the nav bar is in a partial. Here's the link from the header.ejs

```
<!-- views/partials/header.ejs -->
```

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <a class="btn navbutton" >Bio</a></button>
        <a class="btn navbutton" >My Work</a></button>
        <a class="btn navbutton" >Clients</a></button>
        <a class="btn navbutton" href="pages/faq.ejs">FAQ</a></button>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

</div>
```

Here's the server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var html = require('html');


// serve static files from public folder
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/views'));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// ROUTES

app.get('/', function(req,res) {
  res.render('pages/index');
});

app.get('/faq', function(req,res) {
  res.render('pages/faq');
});
```

If it helps, here's the file structure

```
-node_modules
-public
  -css
  -images
  -js
-views
  -partials
  -pages
server.js
```

Comment: Check the request headers..... Some parameter is causing it to be treated  like this and downloaded.

Comment: I think @dman means the *response* headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is here:

```
<a class="btn navbutton" href="pages/faq.ejs">FAQ</a></button>
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
<a class="btn navbutton" href="faq">FAQ</a></button>
```

(no `.ejs`)

**EDIT**

You should also probably remove this line:

```
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
```

I believe this is what's allowing the file to be downloaded instead of returning a 404.

Comment: Great answer, but just to add on a bit, I just use a single public folder for all my images, css, and client JS. The code to do that is really simple:
app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: didn't work. @ Matt West, I use the same file structure

Comment: `href="/pages/faq"` for absolute path.

Comment: Oh, actually, I think it should just be "faq" (or "/faq") to match the route you've set up.

Comment: nope. I've tried every iteration I could think of, it either downloads the page or says Cannot GET ... whatever

Comment: well it stopped downloading it and now it's just hitting  a 404 which I can't figure out why the eff this stupid route isn't connecting. it's the most straightforward route on the planet, arrggghh

Comment: @nwimmer123 Can you get the page to load if you just browse to `/faq` manually? And to clarify, I assume that `views/pages` has both `index.ejs` and `faq.ejs` in it?

Comment: @smarx yes, both pages are in the pages folder, and no I can't open it manually, either by typing it's full file path or it's relative path form local host. Or by right clicking on it and clicking on "Open in Browser". I'd assume that's because it's an EJS and not an HTML file

Comment: @smark, for some reason redoing the path to just faq worked today. maybe the route was cached before or something. Thanks!